# *ngFor dynamic string interpolation with array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngfor

Actually i have the situation that i want to change the array looping dynamically.

```
export interface City { 
   street: Street[];
   country: Country[];
}

<div>
    <div (click)="OnClick()">Street</div>
    <div (click)="OnClick()">Country</div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="clicked">       
         <div *ngFor="let c of city.street">    
              <div>
                {{c.name}}          
              </div>        
         </div>  
</div>
```

If the User click on Street, the Values of the street should loop.

> expected: *ngFor="let c of city.street"

If the user click on country, the values of the country should loop.

> expected: *ngFor="let c of city.country"

I have tried the following:

```
<div>
    <div (click)="OnClick('street')">Street</div>
    <div (click)="OnClick('country')">Country</div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="clicked">       
         //Porperty Binding
         <div *ngFor="let c of city.{{onClickParameter}}">  
              <div>
                {{c.name}}          
              </div>        
         </div>  
</div>
```

It doenst work ( Template Parse Error because city.{{}} )
Is thereother solutions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use component function to handle it:

```
//Component
export interface City { 
 street: Street[];
 country: Country[];
}

export class MyComponent {
  public selected : string = 'street';
  public city: City;

  OnClick(select: string) {
    this.selected = select;
  }

}

// You HTML

<div>
  <div (click)="OnClick('street')">Street</div>
  <div (click)="OnClick('country')">Country</div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="clicked">       
  <div *ngFor="let c of city[selected]">  
    <div>{{c.name}}</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: You could simplify the template further by moving `city[selected]` into the class using e.g. a property `get listOfThings() { return this.city[this.selected]; }`